# finite groups all of whose maximal subgroups are cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group and let all of maximal subgroups of $G$ are cyclic. What can we say about the structure of $G$?

Comment: You have $Q_8$ which has $3$ maximal subgroups each of them being cyclic.but the group itself isn't even abelian.

Comment: in general what can we say about $G$?

Comment: I dont know what can be said in general.i guess nothing can be said apart from giving some extra conditions on G.that is why i posted it as a comment not as an answer

Comment: consider Klein-4 group which also has 4 cyclic subgroup but the group is not cyclic but abelian.